# Transposing dimensions after a reshape: when it is required?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

`tf.reshape` can change the dimension of a tensor data structure, but is there any guarantee about how will be the data ordered on each dimension?

suppose I have a tensor with dimensions `A[objects, x, t]` that describes some value across different objects, positions and time, and another that is just across `B[x,t]`. I usually have to do reshapes in order to copy `B` over dimensions 0 like this:

```
B_res = tf.tile( tf.reshape( B , [1, X_SIZE, T_SIZE]), tf.pack([OBJECT_SIZE,1,1]))
some_op = tf.mul( A, B_res )
```

The problem I see is when `X_SIZE == T_SIZE` reshape does not have any way to know how to arrange B data in the reshape, for all that I know, it could be aligning data along dimension 0 of `B` along dimension 2 of `B_res`!

Is there any rules for how `reshape` orders data? I want to know if a few `tf.transpose` operations are required after a certain `tf.reshape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In memory arrays / tensors are really just 1D objects.  So say you need to store a 10x10 array.  In memory this would just be a 1D array of length 100 where the first 10 elements correspond to the first row.  This is known as row major ordering.  Say you want to reshape it to the shape 20x5.  The underlying memory is not changed by the reshape so the first ten elements now make up rows 1 and 2.  Transpose on the other hand physically reorders the memory to maintain the row major ordering while changing the location of the dimensions.

Also I think you are tiling unessarily.  You should read up on broadcasting.  I think you could do the following.

```
some_op = A * tf.reshape(B, [1, X_SIZE, T_SIZE])
```

In this case it will automatically broadcast B along the first dimension of A.

Note.  I am not actually sure if tensorflow is using row major or column major ordering but the same concepts still apply.

Comment: good points, I'll keep that in mind, thank you. But the question is about how `reshape` might or might not shuffle dimensions in general (specially when some of the dimensions are equal, which might result in ambiguity). What if one asks a `reshape(B, [1, T_SIZE, X_SIZE])`?

Comment: That was the point I was making about memory order.  There is no ambiguity.  All of the items maintain the same underlying 1D order with reshape.  There is just a different shape placed over it.  Kind of like how you can view 100 elements as just 100 elements, 10x10 elements, or 5x5x4 elements.  The memory order does not change.  Just the dimensions.  Reshape does not shuffle dimensions.

Comment: for now I'm replacing all cases of `reshape` with `expand_dims`, although I'm already doing a few replacements in terms of broadcasting rules when it is obvious what broadcasting is doing. I didn't knew that broadcasting also applies to all elementwise operators like +, I thought it was only for multiplication.

Comment: I think it is for everything.